# sending parsed JSON file to client but format is not HTML

Tags: html, node.js, json, html-parsing, jsdom

called the API, and parsed the JSON. Now want to display that parsed JSOn in table format in receiving page. it is coming as plain text.
API url is just for test purpose taken from WIKI, cannot post actual API for security purpose.

requiremtn is to send the HTMl file in table format as a output.

**app.js file:**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const https = require("https");
    var fs = require('fs');
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });

    app.post("/", function(req, res) {

      const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
   format=json&action=parse&page=Anthony%20Martial";

      https.get(url, function(response) {

     https.get(url, (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    const jsonDATA = JSON.parse(data).parse;
    var jsonText = jsonDATA.text;
    var jsonTitle = jsonDATA.title;
    var jsonPageid = jsonDATA.pageid

    var str = JSON.stringify(jsonText);

    var str1 = str.replace(/\\n/g, '');
    const jsdom = require("jsdom");
    const {
      JSDOM
    } = jsdom;

    const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();

    const dom = new JSDOM(str1, {
      virtualConsole,
      runScripts: "dangerously",
      resources: "usable"
    });
    var strWrite = dom.window.document.querySelector("table").textContent;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.write(strWrite);
    res.send();
      });
     });
       });
    });
    app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
     console.log("server is running in port 3000");
    });
```

**index.html file:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>weatehr App API</title>
      <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      
    </head>

    <body>

      <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="cityInput">City Name:</label>
        <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="cityName">
         <button type="submit"> Go </button>
        <h3>hello</h3>
      </form>
  
      <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**output i am receiving:
in plaintext format:**

Anthony MartialMartial playing for Manchester United in 2017Personal informationFull nameAnthony
Jordan Martial[1]Date of birth (1995-12-05) 5 December 1995 (ageÂ 24)[2]Place of birthMassy,
FranceHeight1.81Â m (5Â ft 11Â in)[3]Playing position(s)ForwardClub informationCurrent
teamManchester UnitedNumber9Youth career2001â€“2009CO Les Ulis2009â€“2012LyonSenior
career*YearsTeamApps(Gls)2012â€“2013Lyon B11(5)2013Lyon3(0)2013Monaco
B4(3)2013â€“2015Monaco49(11)2015â€“Manchester United143(51)National teamâ€¡2010â€“2011France
U1617(9)2011â€“2012France U1713(9)2012â€“2013France U184(3)2013France U195(0)2013â€“2015France
U2112(4)2015â€“France18(1) Honours Representing Â FranceMen's footballUEFA European
ChampionshipRunner-up2016 France* Senior club appearances and goals counted for the domestic
league only and correct as of 21:16, 16 July 2020 (UTC)â€¡ National team caps and goals correct
as of 27 March 2018

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

option1:
using repalce statement that parsed JSON escape charatacter has been removed from the string.
An now the display it exactly in table format.

option2:
concatenate   and  tag then at the end close    tag .
Then it is coming as a table.